# My Register activity is not running. The Text view link on the log in page takes me back to the main activity instead of the log in page.Please advice

Tags: java, android, android-studio

The Text view link on the log in page takes me back to the main activity instead of the log in page.What could be the problem? I already put the Reigister Activity in the Launcher
This is my Manifest

```
    <activity android:name=".Login"/>
    <activity android:name=".Register"
        android:exported="true">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"/>
```

Login.java

```
        mLoginBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String email = mEmail.getText().toString().trim();
            String password = mPassword.getText().toString().trim();

            if(TextUtils.isEmpty(email)){
                mEmail.setError("Email is Required.");
                return;
            }
            if(TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){
                mPassword.setError("Enter password");
                return;
            }
            if(password.length()< 6){
                mPassword.setError("Password must be more than 6 characters");
                return;
            }
            // Authenticate the user
            fAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener((task) -> {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Logged in successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Error!" + task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
    });

    mCreateBtn.setOnClickListener(view -> startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Register.class)));

}
```

}

Comment: Do you want to make `Login.java` as the launcher?

Comment: In Login.java you already put data as when user credential is right then goto MainActivity, If You Want To Go Another Activity Then Put Another Activity Name In startactivity.

Comment: When i make Login.java as the launcher it still goes to the main activity before log in